# Are there standard/common guidelines for CSS?

Tags: css

Are there standard/common guidelines for CSS that you should always follow? For example something like you should only font size 12, 14, 16 (only one of those) for Arail?

Comment: This question makes literally no sense, reword please :)

Comment: I guess that the OP is looking for official documents on best practices.

Comment: I think he/she wants to know if there is a standard guideline for styling font sizes and the sort and/or a "standard" best practice on CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real reason to standardise this sort of thing. Visual glyph size changes between fonts using the same font size, the only thing that remains constant is the font size relative to the other elements in your design.

Ultimately, when building a web design you need to consider many things, including viewing on many different devices (read: different DPI settings) and on hundreds of different resolutions (not even counting those who browse the web without maximizing the browser window) and even different languages and the space the content will take up with different localization settings.

One important thing to consider is how different devices with different DPIs will display the fonts. For this reason it's always a good idea to test out your design by viewing it using all different devices, browsers, and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want with relation to font sizes and fonts be they Arial or any other font.

Best practice is to use color, font sizes and fonts that are legible for the vast majority of users.

By default if you set the font size on your website to be 100% then that equates to 16px.

Most websites these day will use either 14px or 16px as the standard font size but 12px is still quite common too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP question, it seems like he is looking for best practices in accesibility.

But if that's not the case, may the coding standards for Drupal and Wordpress serve you. They suggest how to indent your code, your comments and browser specific hacks.

For Drupal: http://drupal.org/node/302199

For Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS_Coding_Standards

On the other hand, OOCSS and SMACSS suggest better practices for organizing your code. OOCSS suggest creating reusable classes as if they were OOP classes. SMACSS hints on how to organize your rules according to what they are styling.

OOCSS: http://oocss.org/

SMACSS: http://smacss.com/